# Passing a string as a keyed argument to a function

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass an argument to a method with a key to get a Django queryset. The key will be dependent on whatever the user passes through.

Here's an example:

The initial value for filter will be id=1 (a string), I am including a split based on commas in case the user passes in additional filters, such as, title=blahblahblah

```
            filter_split = filters.split(",")
            itemFilter = Items.objects # from Django
            for f in filter_split:
                itemFilter = itemFilter.filter(f)
```

I have also tried splitting the leftover string as two separate values (key and value) and passing them as such:

```
itemFilter = itemFilter.filter(key = value)
```

With no luck.

How can I pass programmatic arguments to a method in Python? Or is there another way to programmatically filter the queryset with Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass programmatic arguments with `*list` and `**dict` in the argument list.

```
a = [2,3,4]
function(1, *a) # equal to function(1,2,3,4)
b = {'x':42, 'y':None}
function(1, **b) # equal to function(1, x=42, y=None)
```

In your case just create a dictionary, assign the key-value pairs from your user input and call `itemFilter.filter(**your_dict)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to pass a string e.g. `"id=1"` to filter.

You can create a dictionary dynamically, then pass it to filter using ** unpacking.

```
key = "id"
value = 1
kwargs = {key: value}
MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Your other approach to try `MyModel.objects.filter(key=value)` doesn't work, because it doesn't use the variable key, it tries to filter on the field 'key'